Range of b for Single Intersection Point Between Line and Curve
Question:
If the straight line $y=x+b$ intersects with the curve $x=\sqrt{1-y^2}$ at exactly one point, then what's the range of $b$? （　　）
A. $b∈(-1，1]$         B. $b=-\sqrt{2}$
C. $b=±\sqrt{2}$              D. $b∈(-1，1]$ Or $b=-\sqrt{2}$
My method is visualize the graphs
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[{x == Sqrt[1 - y^2], y == x + b}, {x, -1.5, 
   1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, Frame -> False, Axes -> True, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {b, -1.5, 1.5}]

Any other method to solve this question?

example 1
Clear[range, sol, result];
range = Reduce[{x == Sqrt[1 - y^2], y == x + b}, {b}, {x, y}, Reals]
sol = Reduce[{x == Sqrt[1 - y^2], y == x + b, range}, {x, y}, 
   Reals][[1]]
result = Select[sol, Length[Cases[#, Equal[x, _], -1]] == 1 &]
Reduce[result, {b}, {x}, Reals]


b == -Sqrt[2] || -1 < b <= 1

The correct answer is D.
ContourPlot[{x == Sqrt[1 - y^2], y == x + -Sqrt[2], 
   y == x + RandomReal[{-1, 1}]} // Evaluate, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 20, PlotRange -> All]


example 2
Clear[eqn,range, sol, result];
eqn = {x == Sqrt[3 - 5 y^2] , y == x + b}
range = Reduce[And @@ eqn, {b}, {x, y}, Reals]
sol = Reduce[{And @@ eqn, range}, {x, y}, Reals][[1]]
result = Select[sol, Length[Cases[#, Equal[x, _], -1]] == 1 &]
Reduce[result, {b}, {x}, Reals]


b == -3 Sqrt[2/5] || -Sqrt[(3/5)] < b <= Sqrt[3/5]

ContourPlot[{x == Sqrt[3 - 5 y^2], y == x + (-3  Sqrt[2/5]), 
   y == x + RandomReal[{-Sqrt[(3/5)], Sqrt[3/5]}]} // 
  Evaluate, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 PlotPoints -> 20]


example 3
Clear[eqn,range, sol, result];
eqn = {y == x^3, y == x + b, -1 <= x <= 1}
range = Reduce[And @@ eqn, {b}, {x, y}, Reals]
sol = Reduce[{And @@ eqn, range}, {x, y}, Reals][[1]]
result = Select[sol, Length[Cases[#, Equal[x, _], -1]] == 1 &]
Reduce[result, {b}, {x}, Reals]


b == -(2/(3 Sqrt[3])) || b == 2/(3 Sqrt[3])

ContourPlot[{y == x^3, y == x + -(2/(3 Sqrt[3])), 
   y == x + 2/(3 Sqrt[3])} // Evaluate, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 20, PlotRange -> All]



From two equations $x = \sqrt{1 - y^2}$ and  $y = x + b $, we have
$$y - \sqrt{1 - y^2} = b.$$
You can plot the graph of the function $y - \sqrt{1 - y^2}$.
We find extra point of the function
f[y_] = y - Sqrt[1 - y^2]
f[y] /. Solve[f'[y] == 0, y]


{-Sqrt[2]}

We plot the graph
Plot[{1, -1, -Sqrt[2], y - Sqrt[1 - y^2]}, {y, -1, 1}]


From this graph, we have all values of $b$ is
$b = -\sqrt{2}$  or $-1 < b \leqslant 1$.
